# PTIJ: Why are we blessing Hashem for the groom and challah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I've been to many *sheva berachos* celebrations. After the meal, the seven blessings conferred to a newly married husband and wife are recited. The beginning of the final blessing has bothered me for many years.

[Seventh blessing](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Birkat_Hamazon%2C_ShevaBrachot.6?vhe=Sheva_Brachot&lang=bi):

> בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְיָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם, אֲשֶׁר בָּרָא שָׂשׂוֹן וְשִׂמְחָה **חָתָן וְכַלָּה**, גִּילָה רִנָּה דִּיצָה וְחֶדְוָה, אַהֲבָה וְאַחְוָה וְשָׁלוֹם וְרֵעוּת. מְהֵרָה יְיָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ יִשָּׁמַע בְּעָרֵי יְהוּדָה וּבְחוּצוֹת יְרוּשָׁלַיִם, קוֹל שָׂשׂוֹן וְקוֹל שִׂמְחָה, קוֹל חָתָן וְקוֹל כַּלָּה, קוֹל מִצְהֲלוֹת חֲתָנִים מֵחֻפָּתָם, וּנְעָרִים מִמִּשְׁתֵּה נְגִינָתָם. בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְיָ, מְשַׂמֵּחַ חָתָן עִם הַכַּלָּה.
>
> Blessed are you Hashem, our G-d, the King of the Universe, who created joy and gladness, **groom and *challah***, mirth and exultation, pleasure, delight, love, brotherhood, peace, and fellowship. Hashem, our G-d, speedily let it be heard in the streets of Jerusalem, the sound of joy and the sound of happiness, the sound of the groom and the sound of the bride, the jubilant sound of grooms from their canopies, and children from their parties of song. Blessed are you Hashem, Who gladdens the groom with his bride.

Why at the beginning of the blessing are we blessing G-d for the groom and ***challah***? What about the bride? Why is she ignored...? What's worse, the rest of the blessing even mentions the bride! Why the inconsistency? I've always wondered why no one else has pointed this out...

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 0):

It is because challah is a clear sign that this is a holy union. As the midrash in [Bereishis Rabbah 60](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.60?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi) brings down:

> וַיְבִאֶהָ יִצְחָק הָאֹהֱלָה שָׂרָה אִמּוֹ (בראשית כד, סז), כָּל יָמִים שֶׁהָיְתָה שָׂרָה קַיֶּמֶת הָיָה עָנָן קָשׁוּר עַל פֶּתַח אָהֳלָהּ, כֵּיוָן שֶׁמֵּתָה פָּסַק אוֹתוֹ עָנָן, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁבָּאת רִבְקָה חָזַר אוֹתוֹ עָנָן. כָּל יָמִים שֶׁהָיְתָה שָׂרָה קַיֶּמֶת הָיוּ דְּלָתוֹת פְּתוּחוֹת לִרְוָחָה, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁמֵּתָה שָׂרָה פָּסְקָה אוֹתָהּ הָרְוָחָה, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁבָּאת רִבְקָה חָזְרָה אוֹתָהּ הָרְוָחָה. **וְכָל יָמִים שֶׁהָיְתָה שָׂרָה קַיֶּמֶת הָיָה בְּרָכָה מְשֻׁלַּחַת בָּעִסָּה, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁמֵּתָה שָׂרָה פָּסְקָה אוֹתָהּ הַבְּרָכָה, כֵּיוָן שֶׁבָּאת רִבְקָה חָזְרָה**. כָּל יָמִים שֶׁהָיְתָה שָׂרָה קַיֶּמֶת הָיָה נֵר דּוֹלֵק מִלֵּילֵי שַׁבָּת וְעַד לֵילֵי שַׁבָּת, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁמֵּתָה פָּסַק אוֹתוֹ הַנֵּר, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁבָּאת רִבְקָה חָזַר. **וְכֵיוָן שֶׁרָאָה אוֹתָהּ שֶׁהִיא עוֹשָׂה כְּמַעֲשֵׂה אִמּוֹ, קוֹצָה חַלָּתָהּ בְּטָהֳרָה וְקוֹצָה עִסָּתָהּ בְּטָהֳרָה, מִיָּד וַיְּבִאֶהָ יִצְחָק הָאֹהֱלָה**. אָמַר רַבִּי יוּדָן לִמְדָתְךָ תּוֹרָה שֶׁאִם יִהְיֶה לָאָדָם בָּנִים גְּדוֹלִים יִהְיֶה מַשִֹּׂיאָן מִתְּחִלָּה וְאַחַר כָּךְ הוּא נוֹשֵׂא לוֹ אִשָּׁה, מִמִּי אַתָּה לָמֵד מֵאַבְרָהָם, בַּתְּחִלָּה וַיְבִאֶהָ יִצְחָק הָאֹהֱלָה שָׂרָה אִמּוֹ, וְאַחַר כָּךְ (בראשית כה, א): וַיֹּסֶף אַבְרָהָם וַיִּקַּח אִשָּׁה.
>
> "And Isaac brought her into the tent of Sarah, his mother-" All the days that Sarah was alive, a cloud was connected (lit. tied) to the entrance of her tent. When she died, the cloud stopped [resting at her tent.] And when Rebecca came, the cloud returned. All the days that Sarah was alive, the doors were open wide. When she died, the wideness stopped. And when Rebecca came, the wideness returned. **And all the days that Sarah was alive, there was a blessing in her dough, and when Sarah died, that blessing ended. When Rebecca came, [the blessing] returned**. All the days that Sarah was alive, there was a candle that would burn from Sabbath Eve to [the next] Sabbath Eve, and when she died, the candle stopped [burning for so long]. And when Rebecca came, [the week-long flame of the candle] returned. **And as soon as [Isaac] saw her, that she did the deeds of his mother, separating her challah in purity and separating her dough in purity, he brought her into the tent.** Rabbi Yudan said, "The Torah teaches you, that if a man has grown-up sons, he should marry them off first and then he should marry. Who do you learn [this teaching] from? From Abraham: first, "And Isaac brought her into the tent of Sarah his mother," and afterwards, "And Abraham took another wife, and her name was Keturah."

We thus bless the married couple that the groom should see the same level of purity performed with the challah as it is a good harbinger that the chosson should duly 'bring her into his tent'.